# Как реализовать схему nginx-nginx ssl?

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, iptables

На фронтенде nginx, на бакэнде nginx с сертификатами.

Как мне пробросить запросы на бакэнд? или надо пробросить сертификаты на фронтенд?

Сейчас напрямую форвардятся все запросы к 443 на бакэнд через iptables, но реальный ip адрес не передается, а надо.

Через iptables этого [не сделать](https://serverfault.com/questions/704406/original-ip-lost-with-iptables-nat-to-another-server), надо как-то через nginx.

Comment: Либо настроить iptables по-человечески, либо перенести ssl на фронт. Вообще не очень понятен смысл фронта если у вас один бекенд

Comment: так надо как то в виртуалку заруливать то? как ip tables настроить в данном случае?

Comment: Ключевые слова: iptables DNAT. Nginx на фронте в таком случае вообще не нужен.

Comment: попробовал ошибка получается SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Comment: И что? Мы должны телепатически угадать что именно вы не так сделали?

Comment: iptables -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.200:443

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/690427/iptables-nat-doesnt-preserve-remote-ip

Comment: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.22:2 вбил это правило работать работает, но ip адрес не пробрасывает

Comment: Эээ, а вы вообще прочитали о чём там?

Comment: ну я понял что надо это добавить еще iptables -A POSTROUTING -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE

Comment: М-дя. Рекомендую всё же прочитать, осмыслить, а потом применить под свою задачу. Вы хотя бы понимаете что делает команда выше?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40438/discussion-between---and-alexey-ten).

Comment: Что обсуждение уже ушло в сторону от основного вопроса. Создайте новый вопрос про iptables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > Через iptables этого не сделать (ссылка)

   по ссылке описана несколько иная сетевая схема: два сервера, подключенные к интернету независимо друг от друга.

   в вашем же случае (когда у второй машины шлюзом по умолчанию указана первая) это вполне реализуемо: [Проброс реального ip-адреса в виртуальную машину за nat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/528595/178576)
2. но более гибким решением, по-моему, будет обработка *ssl* на первой из машин («шлюзе»). тогда из поступающих *http**s***-запросов можно будет узнать целевое доменное имя и проксировать уже *http-* (не *http**s**-*) пакеты на нужные *http-серверы* внутри вашей сети. а на этих серверах уже можно принимать и обрабатывать *http-* (не *http**s**-*) трафик.

   для того же, чтобы дать понять этим серверам, что *https* таки используется, можно устанавливать [де-факто стандартный заголовок *x-forwarder-proto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_request_fields), и эти серверы затем смогут сообщить сайтам об этом факте (например, некоторые *cms* имеют привычку делать редирект на *https*, если «обнаруживают», что используется *http*, например, для авторизации пользователей).

   как этот заголовок обработать в *apache*, написано, например, [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/142363/):

   ```
   <VirtualHost ...>
     ServerName ...
     ...
     SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
     ...
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   как этот заголовок обработать в *nginx*, написано, например, [здесь](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,11794,11794):

   ```
   server {
     ...
     set_scheme_from ip-адрес-шлюза;
     real_scheme_header X-Forwarded-Proto;
     ...
   }
   ```