# Проброс реального ip-адреса в виртуальную машину за nat

Tags: linux, iptables

Есть вэб-сервер на виртуальной машине.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы весь трафик по 80 и 443 портам заворачивался на эту виртуальную машину без подмены ip-адреса клиента.

Мой iptables:

```
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/16 -o vmbr0 -j SNAT --to-source 'x.x.x.x
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o vmbr1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.1

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 60000:61000 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.200:60000-61000

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i vmbr0 -p tcp -d 'x.x.x.x --dport 18180 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.200:22
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i vmbr0 -p tcp -d 'x.x.x.x --dport 17172 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.102:22
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i vmbr0 -p tcp -d 'x.x.x.x --dport 17171 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.101:22
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i vmbr0 -p tcp -d 'x.x.x.x --dport 3000 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.101:3000
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i vmbr0 -p tcp -d 'x.x.x.x --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.200:443
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i vmbr0 -p tcp -d 'x.x.x.x --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:80

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i vmbr0 -p tcp -s y.y.y.y -d 'x.x.x.x --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.102:80
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i vmbr0 -p tcp -s y.y.y.y -d 'x.x.x.x --dport 8081 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.102:8081

iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p TCP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p TCP --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -s y.y.y.y -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
#iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp --dport 60000:61000 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Comment: Какое решение используется для виртуализации? Их, знаете ли, более  чем одно. Или привести решения для всех?

Comment: В общем случае думаю как и обычный редирект, с помощью DNAT, т.е. подменой адреса назначения на адрес виртуалки

Comment: Как раз Dnat настроен, но в заголовках передается адрес vmbr0

Comment: В каких заголовках, в http, в каких именно и что написано ? (когда отвечаете, пишите явно кому @Mike а то оповещения не приходят и я не в курсе, что мне что то писали

Comment: @Mike Подменяется на адрес шлюза vmbr1 192.168.0.1

Comment: @АнтонВеселов А что именно то подменяется ? И зачем вам кстати правила SNAT ? Ну первое предположим вообще никогда срабатывать не должно. А вот второе ... оно же вам адрес клиента портит при передаче в виртуалку. SNAT вообще не нужен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

как я понял, подразумевается трафик, приходящий на интерфейс `vmbr0` на адрес `x.x.x.x`.

1. вот эти правила надо «привести к общему знаменателю»:

   ```
   iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i vmbr0 -p tcp -d 'x.x.x.x --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.200:443
   iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i vmbr0 -p tcp -d 'x.x.x.x --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:80
   ```

   если целевая виртуальная машина имеет ip-адрес `192.168.0.200`, то и во втором правиле должен фигурировать этот ip-адрес.
2. а это правило надо убрать:

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o vmbr1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.1
   ```
3. на целевой виртуальной машине шлюзом по умолчанию должен быть назначен ip-адрес, который присвоен сетевому интерфейсу (на машине, правила netfilter-а которой приведены в вопросе), «смотрящему» в локальную сеть. насколько я понял — `192.168.0.1`.

Comment: Ну вот да это работает псб